# What Output/Input Stream the binary use?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, inputstream, outputstream

I have a executable binary on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, which i uploaded to http://te.ngok.in/InitSDX

I am wondering what kind of output/input it is using. I need to log all of its output to a file, but simply running

```
./InitSDX seed > log.txt
```

does not populate any text. But when I do

```
./InitSDX > log.txt
```

It does show show error, and logged into the file.

Another method, `./InitSDX seed | less` show nothing, but `./IniSDX | less`, show the error.

Note, simply running `./InitSDX seed` outputs some text on screen.

Can anyone please point something here? What/which output stream should I use and how? Thank you.

UPDATE:
I've tried `InitSDX seed > log.txt > 2>&1` still put no text to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `./InitSDK` outputs to **stderr**. You can redirect it to **stdout** with:

```
./InitSDK seed > log.txt 2>&1
```

You can redirect only stderr to file with:

```
./InitSDK seed 2> error_log.txt
```

Comment: well, I've tried that too. `InitSDX seed > log.txt > 2>&1` still put no text to the file.